# How can I configure passport-github to acknowledge the user on callback?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have an service and my goal is to let a user auth us to his / her Github account via OAuth. The API layer is stateless, so I don't want to maintain any session information. The code I have so far is:

```
  app.use passport.initialize()
  app.use passport.session()

  passport.use new GitHubStrategy
    clientID: global.config.oauth.github.clientID
    clientSecret: global.config.oauth.github.clientSecret
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:9500/auth/github/callback"
    passReqToCallback: true
  , (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) ->
    console.log req.params
    serviceQuery =
      service: 'github'
      provider_id: "#{profile.id}"
      UserId: 13

    global.db.Service.find
      where: serviceQuery
    .then (dbService) ->
      if not dbService
        newService =
          service: 'github'
          token: accessToken
          secret: null
          provider_id: profile.id
          raw: profile._json
          UserId: 13
        global.db.Service.create newService
      else
        dbService.token = accessToken
        dbService.raw = profile._json
        dbService.save()
    .then ->
      done null, true


  app.get '/auth/github/:sessionToken', (req, res, next) ->
    console.log req.params
    next()
  , passport.authenticate 'github',
    scope: 'repo'
    session: false

  app.get '/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github',
    scope: 'repo'
    session: false
  ), (req, res) ->
    res.redirect 'http://localhost:8080/app'
```

So that when the user is directed to `/auth/github/:sessionToken`, I want `passport` to do its magic and redirect the user to github. This works great. But when they return to `/auth/github/callback`, I need to still be able to identify which user it is.

Since this is the API service, it is supposed to be stateless, so as I mentioned before, I'm looking for some way to pass that token to the `/auth/github/callback`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a console log of req.user in your /auth/github/callback. I believe the req.user will still be storing their user information. As it appears in [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) they pass the user information to be displayed by passing in the req.user.

Comment: [This guide](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google) actually displays how to to display the information from google authentication. It appears the google information is displayed in a user.google variable. Maybe try and console log a req.user.github to get their github info.

Comment: But how can it store it if I do not set a session?